# Podio RateLimit on Fileserver

Tags: php, podio, rate-limiting

We're having an issue with the Podio Api or there is something, Podio hasn't documented.

We're making a request to the Api to get an Item with the function `->getItemById()`. This item has file fields and attached files. To edit this files on our server we need the rawData of these files, so we're calling `->getFile()` and `->getRawData()`.

It all works fine. After ~15-20 requests in about ~10 minutes (time and request count varies on every test) We're getting errors from Podio Server. We're getting errors even if we put short delays between the requests (tested to 30 seconds), so I think it's not a "batching request limit". The errors are with the number 420 which is described as RateLimit Error. After a few minutes waiting the error has gone and the Server is responding the correct answer. But we absolutely don't have any plan when this is going to happen.

We made a function to check if we're hitting the RateLimit but there are still remaining, both for the normal request and for the rate limited request. As you can see in the ScreenShots above.

Please don't answer with the link to the Podio Rate Limit Documentation. I read this section multiple times and I know how this limits are set. We're only having our problem when we are calling the file server (files.podio.com) and not when we're making other api requests.

Has anyone had a similar experience with our case?

Functions to call from the PHP Api:

```
/**
 *  get Item by Public ID (in url, starts with 1)
 */
public function getItemById($item_id) {
    try {
        return \PodioItem::get_by_app_item_id($this->app_id, $item_id );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->body['error_description']);
    }
}


public function getFile($file_id) {
    try {
        return \PodioFile::get( $file_id );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->body['error_description']);
    }
}

public function getRawData($file) {
    try {
        return $file->get_raw();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception("Status: " . $e->status . " Message: " . (empty($e->body['error_description']) ? '-' : $e->body['error_description']));
    }
}
```

Call to the Podio Server with the RateLimit call:

```
$podio = new \Podio\Api\Api('APP_ID', 'APP_TOKEN');

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

    echo "Rate Limit: " . $podio->getRateLimitRemaining() . '<br>';

    $item = $podio->getItemById(500);
    echo "Rate Limit: " . $podio->getRateLimitRemaining() . '<br>';

    $file = $podio->getFile(668548372);
    $raw_file = $podio->getRawData($file);

}
```

Browser Output. As you can see the RateLimit is not hit, but we're getting a 420 directly after calling getRawData()

[image]

Podio Support told me, they don't give support to private people despite of we are a company who uses podio on a daily basis and this is in my eyes a bug on their server (or it isn't documented anywhere).

---

Update:
I made a second function to trigger this down:

```
// This function is used to test Podio Fileserver for Rate Limits
public function podioAction() {

    $podio = new \Podio\Api\Api('APP_ID', 'APP_TOKEN');     

    for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {

        try {

            $item = $podio->getItemById(500);
            echo date("H:i:s") . " Rate Limit Remaining: " . $podio->getRateLimitRemaining() . ', EndPoint URL: /app/{$app_id}/item/{$app_item_id} <br>';

            $podio->updateItem($item->item_id, array('titel-intern' => 'API Test'), array(), array('silent' => true));
            echo date("H:i:s") . " Rate Limit Remaining: " . $podio->getRateLimitRemaining() . ', EndPoint URL: /item/{$item_id} <br>';

            $file = $podio->getFile(668548372);
            echo date("H:i:s") . " Rate Limit Remaining: " . $podio->getRateLimitRemaining() . ', EndPoint URL: /file/{$file_id} <br>';

            $raw_file = $podio->getRawData($file);
            echo date("H:i:s") . " File received, EndPoint URL: https://files.podio.com/668548372 " . '<br>';

        } catch(Exception $e) {

            echo date("H:i:s") . " Error: " . $e->getMessage() . " <br>";
            exit;

        }

    }

    exit;

}
```

This gives me to following Browseroutput (the first few lines are not included):

```
15:46:38 Rate Limit Remaining: 4753, EndPoint URL: /app/{$app_id}/item/{$app_item_id} 
15:46:38 Rate Limit Remaining: 8, EndPoint URL: /item/{$item_id} 
15:46:38 Rate Limit Remaining: 4752, EndPoint URL: /file/{$file_id} 
15:46:38 File received, EndPoint URL: https://files.podio.com/668548372 
15:46:39 Rate Limit Remaining: 4751, EndPoint URL: /app/{$app_id}/item/{$app_item_id} 
15:46:39 Rate Limit Remaining: 6, EndPoint URL: /item/{$item_id} 
15:46:39 Rate Limit Remaining: 4750, EndPoint URL: /file/{$file_id} 
15:46:39 File received, EndPoint URL: https://files.podio.com/668548372 
15:46:39 Rate Limit Remaining: 4749, EndPoint URL: /app/{$app_id}/item/{$app_item_id} 
15:46:40 Rate Limit Remaining: 4, EndPoint URL: /item/{$item_id} 
15:46:40 Rate Limit Remaining: 4748, EndPoint URL: /file/{$file_id} 
15:46:40 File received, EndPoint URL: https://files.podio.com/668548372 
15:46:40 Rate Limit Remaining: 4747, EndPoint URL: /app/{$app_id}/item/{$app_item_id} 
15:46:40 Rate Limit Remaining: 2, EndPoint URL: /item/{$item_id} 
15:46:40 Rate Limit Remaining: 4746, EndPoint URL: /file/{$file_id} 
15:46:41 File received, EndPoint URL: https://files.podio.com/668548372 
15:46:41 Rate Limit Remaining: 4745, EndPoint URL: /app/{$app_id}/item/{$app_item_id} 
15:46:41 Rate Limit Remaining: 0, EndPoint URL: /item/{$item_id} 
15:46:41 Rate Limit Remaining: 4744, EndPoint URL: /file/{$file_id} 
15:46:41 Error: Status: 420 Message: -
```

Today in this test everything seems normal. It seems like the files are also RateLimited Requests and are throwing errors when these Limits are off. But in the Screenshot above I had a different result. If it is always like today, there is not a problem and I can track this. But this was not the case in the last few days.

I'm posting again if this happens as it was at the time asking this question, but for now everything seems to work fine.

Comment: It is very normal for API owners not to give private technical support about how you're using their API - it is very similar to web hosts who have to decline requests to help with customer programs. It's just not their job. Of course, if they have a bug, they will be interested in fixing that, but you need to show them _why_ it is their bug and not yours.

Comment: @halfer yes this is possible, but we're customers of podio and paying for the services, so if I would get money from someone, I would offer support. Anyways is my question not showing enough what the problem is and why I'm thinking this is an error in the podio server?

Comment: For API providers and hosts of various kinds, private technical support is often available for an extra fee (on top of what you pay for the core service). This is very normal, since customers would quite cheerfully take enough support to make the company run at a loss, and they would soon go bust.

Comment: I wonder if this question could do with some improvements. (a) please replace the images of text with formatted text, and (b) in relation to the ~15-20 requests, is there any delay between consecutive calls? I wonder if putting a small delay between them so they are at least a few seconds apart might help. For what it is worth, I agree that this sounds like a sensitive rate-limiter.

Comment: (a) It doesn't seem to make a difference if I'm using formatted text or an image because you need the whole api anyway and this doesn't really matter to answer my question. (b) there is a delay from at least a few seconds until the browser is reloaded. The requests are all made in a browser window and not per script

Comment: @halfer I made the changes to my question and tested it again, but the results are still the same

Comment: Alright. Can you produce a text-based table of a set of calls with (a) the endpoint, (b) the time of the call, in seconds, with the first one being zero, (c) the HTTP response. Please add that into your question as a formatted block. I imagine you can write a short PHP program to generate this table. I would then suggest waiting until your ratelimits are back to normal, then running again, to see if the 420 comes back at the same point. Put that discovery in your question as well.

Comment: At that point, you will (potentially) have evidence that you can show the Podio tech support function. If you can amend your supplied code so it can be copy+pasted into a text file and run, that may persuade a support team to investigate. **Make it easy for them** `:-)`.

Comment: (Also, when supplying browser output here, show it here as text please, not images. You can output in a `<pre>` block if that is helpful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->getRawData()` method is marked as internal and it is not listed on https://developers.podio.com/doc/files as available method. You are not supposed to use it :)

Please use `link` attribute of `file` object from `->getFile()` method. And send the regular Authorization header to that endpoint to authenticate for the download. Download is also subject to lower rate limit (as is `->getRawData()` method)

Comment: By regular Authorization header do you mean a way like this: `Podio::get($file->link, array(), array('file_download' => true))->body`? Is there a way to show the image on our page without downloading it? If I'm trying this, I always get redirected to login

Comment: I meant something like this: "curl  -H \"Authorization: OAuth2 #{Podio.client.oauth_token.access_token}\"  <file_link>" . So, you don't use Podio php client to get file content. Treat that link and independent url with resource that you need, and add "Authorization: OAuth2 <access_token>" header to prove that you have rights to download that file.